# Is it possible, with E4, to programmatically change the active workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to implement the "switch workspace" feature of E3 and wonder if there is a preferred way to do it.
My first guess would be to update the eclipse.ini file which contains the default workspace and restart the ResourcePlugin bundle. But it seems a bit hard.

Comment: You have to restart the RCP to switch workspaces, is that what you want?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid the restart of the whole application -a pure e4 one- if possible. Anyway if this is the only way, is the config.ini update the proper way ?

Comment: There is no support for changing the workspace without restarting. 'ResourcePlugin' is 3.x and can't be used in e4 - a pure e4 application really only uses the workspace for metadata unless you write you own resources code.

Comment: Well.. i'm not so pure, i have ResourcePlugin in project dependencies, using it to get the default workspace location. It seems have to implement a file system abstraction like ResourcePlugin to fit my needs

Comment: `Platform.getInstanceLocation()` gives you the location without the resources plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I'll write some new technical stories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as of today with E4 sdk.